# Add rows based on different ranges - How to avoid numerous df calls?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to avoid filtering the entire pandas `df` for *every* 'color' because the actual `df` has thousands of items in `d` to search, and rows are >100M. I tried reading about combining pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex objects, so I could pass a single MultiIndex obj just once for reindexing, but I don't see that as an option in the latest [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). Note ranges vary in start/stop and sometimes primary key 'color' is missing entirely. Is there a more pythonic a quicker way of filling large sets like this?

**Input**

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'], 'trial': [1, 2, 5, 6], 'val1': [99, 88, 77, 66], 'val2': [55, 44, 33, 22]})
d = {'blue': (1, 8), 'red': (0, 5), 'green': (2, 6)}

>>> df
  color  trial  val1  val2
0   red      1    99    55
1   red      2    88    44
2  blue      5    77    33
3  blue      6    66    22
```

**Slow (working) loop**

```
dfs = []
for k, v in d.items():
    r = list(range(v[0], v[1]))
    m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(([k], r), names=['color', 'trial'])
    frame = df.set_index(['color', 'trial']).reindex(m, fill_value='-').reset_index()
    dfs.append(frame)
final = pd.concat(dfs)
```

**Output**

```
>>> final
    color  trial val1 val2
0    blue      1    -    -
1    blue      2    -    -
2    blue      3    -    -
3    blue      4    -    -
4    blue      5   77   33
5    blue      6   66   22
6    blue      7    -    -
0     red      0    -    -
1     red      1   99   55
2     red      2   88   44
3     red      3    -    -
4     red      4    -    -
0   green      2    -    -
1   green      3    -    -
2   green      4    -    -
3   green      5    -    -
```

Comment: Is `df.set_index(['color', 'trial']).reindex((c, n) for c, v in d.items() for n in range(*v)).reset_index()` any more performant?

Comment: Please explain what is it that you are trying to achieve in your question. Thank you.

Comment: A big performance hit in  your current code is that you are setting index each loop though your dictionary.  Set index once head of the loop, then reset_index after the looping.